# How can I make the network boot before mountall in 12.10?

Tags: 12.10, boot, networking, mount, automount

How can I make the network boot service come up before mountall loads network shares in 12.10? Currently, mountall attempts to mount network shares before the network drivers are loaded during the initial boot sequence giving me errors and recommendations for utilising the man pages for MOUNT, MOUNT.CIFS, MOUNT.NFS, etc and while it doesn't create any long term issues once I'm in X, it does slow the boot sequence significantly.

Answer (score 0):

Look in /etc/rc0.d for the service, it will have S##service e.g. S35networking

Renaming it to S36mountall will make it load just after networking. Or make the number 99 and it will load last.

That's all I can think of.

Comment: This won't actually work on systems where mountall is an Upstart job, and not a SysV init job.

Comment: Considering it was from 3 years ago that wouldn't have been an issue. Maybe you should submit an updated answer.